# "This library now requires a C++11 or later compiler..." when compiling 'number_base.hpp' of boost library

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have a c++ project using **boost 1.77.0** library. The compiler is **g++ 4.8.5**, and as I know it supports the c++11 standard. The following command is used to compile the project:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp Logger.cpp MOCMesh.cpp Mesh.cpp CFDMesh.cpp Solver.cpp -o main -I../tools -I/usr/code/include -I. -L/usr/code/lib -lgmp -lphtread -lmpfr
```

However, I got errors told c++ standard unsatisfied:

```
/usr/code/include/boost/multiprecision/detail/number_base.hpp:36:2: error: #error "This library now requires a C++11 or later compiler - this message was generated as a result of BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_TYPE_TRAITS being set"
 #error "This library now requires a C++11 or later compiler - this message was generated as a result of BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_TYPE_TRAITS being set"
...
```

For some reasons, I cannot update the GNU compilers to latest or higher version, so is there anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: IIRC, GCC 4.9 was the first version with full support of C++11.  Can use an older version of the boost library that doesn't require C++11?

Comment: Even 4.9 is *ancient*. If you can you really should upgrade GCC. It's up to version 11 now, with version 12 being worked on.

Comment: why can't you upgrade to an even higher version?

Comment: GCC 4.8.0 was released 2013-Mar, and the dot-dot release GCC 4.8.5 was released 2015-Jun.  The Boost versions of that timeframe are 1.54 through 1.57.  Not much of a surprise if 1.77 has evolved past what GCC 4.8.5 supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an older version of boost from that time period